# Is it possible to open DOCS, XLSX, PDF files from a shared folder to edit the file in the intranet from a Angular-App?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-mvc, samba

The use-case of this topic is as follows.
The user works within the angular app to capture data for specific cases. In addition to every case the user can upload files in the angular app.
Now if the user reopens the case and wants to edit the uploaded file I'd like to show him links for every file and when he clicks on a link the file should not be delivered from the server with a stream, but should him kind of redirect to the local location of the file on the shared folder like `file:///X:/TheShare/file2edit.doc`
So Word opens up and the user can make changes to the file and directly save the file on the location. So there is no subsequent upload neccessary for the file to be updated on the servers drive where the shared folder points to.
My working environment is an angular(7) frontend which interacts with a spring-mvc backend.
The user working on windows clients with Firefox/Chrome/Edge and the shared folder is available via samba from an linux server whichs hosts the spring backend.

Comment: ASAIK even if you were able to redirect the browser to the proper path, it will simply download a copy of the file.

Comment: This sounds not good. The customer was used to work like this with an old VisualBasic desktop program. We wanted to make the switch to the web-app as convenient as possible, but it's a big loss of quality. Is there another solution for this?